# Create Offline Refund in Woocommerce

Tags: python-3.x, woocommerce

I want to create a refund in woocommerce for an order without using the payment gateway. For that I need to set the property, api_refund whose default value is True to False. How can I send the parameter without changing the url to post to the API?

Comment: The parameters is passed as a body of the request, not in the URL. You don't change the URL. See the [api documentation](http://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/?python#order-refund-properties) for details.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid Thanks man for answering my stupid question, it worked!

Answer (score 0):

I have used in React.js as:

```
//Action for Full refund Order
const fullRefund = (order_id,net_total) => (dispatch) => {
  const data = {
    amount: "20",
    api_refund:false,
    
  };
  
  apiWoo.post( "orders" + "/" + order_id + "/" + "refunds", data)
    .then((response) => {
      console.log("Response Status:", response.status);
      console.log("Response Headers:", response.headers);
      console.log("Response Data:", response.data);
      console.log("Total of pages:", response.headers['x-wp-totalpages']);
      console.log("Total of items:", response.headers['x-wp-total']);
      alert('Full Refund created for the customer');
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error.response.data);
    });
```